# How send notification with Firebase in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase

I am using the firebase.i just want to notify the user to new data enter in firebase.is it possible or not.please help me.

Comment: Given that we're talking of software, it is very likely that what you want is possible. But you're going to have to do some legwork before we can help you on StackOverflow. Read the Firebase [quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html) and [programming guides](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/) for iOS, try building your app and then when you get stuck: come back with a concrete question. You will have learnt a lot and it will be more likely we can help you by then.

Comment: ok.thank you frank.i have solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

> **After Reading many solution and Reading Firebbase poor doc 
>    i can get best solution for that.**
>
> here see solution for that => [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667753/ios-firebase-push-notifications-how-to-give-firebase-users-device-token-and-s/37789322#37789322)