# Firebase Cloud Messaging Doesn't Create Push Notifications but Gets Information

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-notifications

I was working through this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsWHzU1DxjM) to try and put push notifications into my iOS app. I was able to successfully get the certificate for APNS and set the "push notification" and "background modes" capabilities to on. Also, Firebase is able to get the info from the notification when I send one from the firebase console. However, when the app is running in the background the banner notifications never appear. I feel like I may have had a problem converting the tutorial from Objective-C to Swift because the tutorial was in Objective-C, but I'm not sure. I put my AppDelegate class and the program output if that helps at all.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    connectToFcm()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(tokenRefreshCallback),
        name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification,
        object: nil)

    let allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType(arrayLiteral: UIUserNotificationType.Sound, UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge)
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: allNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

override init() {
    FIRApp.configure()
    FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = false
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    connectToFcm()
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    //try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
}

func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}


func tokenRefreshCallback(notification: NSNotification) {
    let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
    print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    if (refreshedToken != nil)
    {
        connectToFcm()
    }

    }

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print message ID.
    print("\(userInfo)")
    //print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("name", object: userInfo)

    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
}
}
```

Console log:

```
2016-06-20 19:14:50.801 MapKitTry[2244:721460] Configuring the default app.
2016-06-20 19:14:50.839 MapKitTry[2244:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started
2016-06-20 19:14:50.846 MapKitTry[2244:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see -omitted-)
2016-06-20 19:14:50.849: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-06-20 19:14:50.849: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
2016-06-20 19:14:50.853: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.1.0
2016-06-20 19:14:50.863: <FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification receiver handlers. Add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-06-20 19:14:50.902 MapKitTry[2244:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
no login
2016-06-20 19:14:51.076 MapKitTry[2244:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
Connected to FCM.
[notification: {
body = "Push notification";
e = 1;
}, collapse_key: pdrum3.KingOfTheTown, from: 302278087187]
%@ [notification: {
body = "Push notification";
e = 1;
}, collapse_key: pdrum3.KingOfTheTown, from: 302278087187]
```

Comment: Here u can See my demo=> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667753/ios-firebase-push-notifications-how-to-give-firebase-users-device-token-and-s/37789322#37789322

Comment: This property is used to set the APNS Token received by the application delegate.
FIRMessaging uses method swizzling to ensure the APNS token is set automatically. However, if you have disabled swizzling by setting FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in your app's Info.plist, you should manually set the APNS token in your application delegate's -application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: method.
If you would like to set the type of the APNS token, rather than relying on automatic detection, see: -setAPNSToken:type:.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Add `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` type "Boolean" value "NO" in your info.plist:

[image: info.plist-image]

Comment: Its been 2 days and finally I found the right solution.

Comment: This property is used to set the APNS Token received by the application delegate.
FIRMessaging uses method swizzling to ensure the APNS token is set automatically. However, if you have disabled swizzling by setting FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in your app's Info.plist, you should manually set the APNS token in your application delegate's -application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: method.
If you would like to set the type of the APNS token, rather than relying on automatic detection, see: -setAPNSToken:type:.

Comment: How to add FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled

Comment: Goto your Flutter project ios folder open it in Xcode and into the runner folder you can see the info.plist file open the file and click the information property list plus button and pest this and typle boolean and value is NO or 0

Comment: Boolean => 0 not NO

Answer (score 6):

I also had to add this to my `AppDelegate`, as advised [here](https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/64).

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

Comment: Was looking everywhere for this solution, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Add this inside your info.plist file, open it as source code(info.plist file)

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the UNUserNotificationDelegate methods that allow you to get notifications.

```
extension NotificationManager: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {

        switch response.actionIdentifier {

        // NotificationActions is a custom String enum I've defined
        case NotificationActions.HighFive.rawValue:
            print("High Five Delivered!")
        default: break
        }
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        // Delivers a notification to an app running in the foreground.
    }
}
```

These two delegate methods replace the old ones you're currently using to receive (i.e. didReceiveRemoteNotification). See this tutorial for more information: http://cleanswifter.com/ios-10-local-notifications/