# Firebase Notification doesn't work in background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have set up Firebase into my swift application using CocoPods

here is some part of my AppDelegate.swift

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    FIRApp.configure()


    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                               name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    return true
}

      func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
            // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
            FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        }

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            connectToFcm()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
//        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("userNotificationCenter:User Info = ", userInfo)

    }

    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        // Won't connect since there is no token
        guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
            return;
        }

        // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }

}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("FIRMessagingDelegate:applicationReceivedRemoteMessage", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```

The current status that when I send a notification from Firebase console it is received and shown in the log as I print in `applicationReceivedRemoteMessage`

What I want to ask about:

1. The application doesn't show a notification in the notification bar.
2. The application should be in foreground, If it is background or force closed the log shows nothing and of course there is no a notification. So can I receive it while in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing part was to add Add FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled type "Boolean" value "NO" in your info.plist

My reference was 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38445657/2294985