# Error 501 when registering for push notifications with Firebase

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I migrated an existing iOS app that was using GCM to Firebase and implemented all methods exactly like the sample code. However, I keep getting an error whenever the app tries to get an instance id. The logged messages are:

```
2016-07-05 16:41:49.298: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=501 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.firebase.iid error 501.)"
2016-07-05 16:42:01.676: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=501 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.firebase.iid error 501.)"
2016-07-05 16:42:26.735: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=501 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.firebase.iid error 501.)"
2016-07-05 16:43:05.580: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=501 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.firebase.iid error 501.)"
2016-07-05 16:44:03.260: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=501 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.firebase.iid error 501.)"
2016-07-05 16:44:03.261: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to retrieve the default GCM token after 5 retries
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I contacted Firebase support and they couldn't help.

Knowing that this is an app that was working fine before switching to Firebase, I know that push configurations on the app side are working. And considering that all the configuration on the Firebase Console was imported from my previous Google Project, I know that my certificates are all working as well (they are the same certificates).

In an attempt to check whether my app code was the problem, I ran the sample app (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging/FCMSwift), changing the Bundle Identifier and using my project's GoogleService-info.plist file and the result is the same 501 error, which leaves me no doubt that the problem is not with the app code.

Does anyone have any clue how to solve this?

Comment: See my Code here=> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667753/ios-firebase-push-notifications-how-to-give-firebase-users-device-token-and-s/37789322#37789322

Comment: Could you try a pod update and double check that you are using the latest version of Instance ID? It should be 1.0.7

Comment: 1.0.7 broke my project. 1.0.6 still works. on 1.0.7 you get the remote token however if you go to console and try to fire it off to a single device it does nothing