# Correct way to retrieve token for FCM - iOS 10 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i had implement Firebase with FirebaseAuth/FCM etc and did sent notification successfully through Firebase Console.

However i would need to push the notification from my own app server.

i am wondering below which way is correct way to retrieve the registration id for the device:-

**1) retrieve registration id token from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }

    print("Registration succeeded!")
    print("Token: ", token)
    Callquery(token)

}
```

**2) Retrieve Registration token from firebase** (Based on Firebase document which retrieve the current registration token)

```
let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
```

i was using the first way, the push notification is not being received even the registration id is stored on my app server database accordingly and i get this CURL session result :-

```
{"multicast_id":6074293608087656831,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

i had also tried the second way and get fatal error while running the app as below:-
[image]

appreciated if anyone could point me the right way, thanks!

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667753/ios-firebase-push-notifications-how-to-give-firebase-users-device-token-and-s

Comment: Note: the deviceToken parameter in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDeviceToken is NOT the Firebase registration token. You still need to call return InstanceID.instanceID().token() as explained below.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `tokenRefreshNotification` function doesn't always get called when launching the app.

However, when placing the code inside the regular `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` delegate function, I can get the token every time:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
}
```

(Swift 3 + Firebase 4.0.4)

Comment: hi, how to post request token  ?

Comment: In case anybody did what I did, the deviceToken:Data parameter is NOT the FCM registration token. The token from InstanceID().token() IS.

Comment: I get 'token()' is deprecated: Use instanceIDWithHandler: instead. for token()

Comment: I did this instead:         InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("InstanceID token: \(result)")
            } else {
                print(error, ": Error in getting token for Fire")
            }
        }

Comment: What about [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)? Registration tokens are delivered via the method `messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:`. This method is called generally once per app start with registration token.

Answer (score 46):

**The recommended way by Firebase:**

```
let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
```

Reference : [Setting Up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

Answer (score 24):

### Swift 3 + Firebase 4.0.4 :

```
static var FirebaseToken : String? {
    return InstanceID.instanceID().token()
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification; what is the difference between yours and the answer below (`Messaging.messaging().fcmToken`)? @MBH

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615817/what-is-the-difference-between-firinstanceid-instanceid-token-and-messaging

Answer (score 21):

## Swift 4 + Firebase (5.3.0)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
        } else if let result = result {
            print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**

Courtesy of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50945350/1014164

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
    } else if let result = result {
        print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
    }
}
```

Comment: i got "Static member 'instanceID' cannot be used " when called in the homescreen viewdidload, **can u help?**

Comment: @kemdo make sure you're writing `InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID` with the parenthesis and not `InstanceID.instanceID.instanceID`

Comment: @kemdo , Yocoh , How did you solve this when i get  Static member 'instanceID...... issue  ?

Answer (score 6):

**FCM Device Token swift3**

```
    let fcmDeviceToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
    print("FCM token: \(fcmDeviceToken ?? "")")
```

Answer (score 5):

Go with the second option, and this is going to seem really stupid/simple, but to fix that nil optional fatal error, just remove the force-unwrap at the end

Your code:
`var token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!`
Make it:
`var token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()`

That will at least fix that nasty crash

Comment: Hi John, the error still there, it seems like the FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() returning nil.

Comment: @aznelite89, the reason why it's nil is that you haven't registered for Firebase Cloud Messaging

Answer (score 5):

First register for the firebase token refresh notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
     #selector(tokenRefreshNotification), name:     
     NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
```

Then you can receive the token in the tokenRefreshNotification selector:

```
func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
      print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}
```

Comment: Note that `InstanceIDTokenRefresh` and `FIRInstanceID` are now deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

**To Get current FCM Token**

```
if let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken {
    // token is current fcmToken
}
```

**To Renew current FCM Token**

If we delete current instanceId, new token will be received vi MessagingDelegate (messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken) a moment later.

```
InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID { (error) in
    if let er = error {
        print(er.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        print("instanceID().deleteID  success ---------------➤")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, but could not figure out what was going on.

The `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` suggested by @Sam is called (almost) every time, so it is a good work around. BUT, it is NOT called the first time you open the app with the refreshed token.

So for this scenario you still need the:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Refreshed Token: \(fcmToken)")
}
```

So if you only use the:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    if let fcmToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(fcmToken)")
    }
}
```

You will only get the "refreshed token" the second time the user opens the app.

I managed to force a refresh token by uninstalling the app and cleaning the Build Folder (Product > Clean Build Folder). Good for testing.

Ideally it could all be handled at `messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken` delegate method, but I was not able to make it work. Another way to get notified for changes in the FCM token is to listen `NSNotification` named `kFIRMessagingRegistrationTokenRefreshNotification` as suggested in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Answer (score 1):

First import the libraries like:

```
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
```

set Delegate:**MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate**

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
```

Write this code on didFinishLaunching():

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    
    //remote Notifications
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (isGranted, err) in
            if err != nil {
                //Something bad happend
            } else {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge,.sound,.alert], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        })
    }else{
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge,.sound,.alert], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    
    return true
}
```

Write connectFCM method like this way:

```
func ConnectToFCM() {
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
    
    if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n ====== TOKEN DCS: " + token)
    }
```

Also write delegate methods for registering and receiving push notification:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("\n\n\n\n\n ==== FCM Token:  ",fcmToken)
    HelperFunction.helper.storeInUserDefaultForKey(name: kFCMToken, val: fcmToken)
    ConnectToFCM()
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    
   // UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
    
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Barker"), object: nil)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
   
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    
    print(userInfo)
    
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
        
}
```

Now we can test it from firebase console.

**100% working, easy and tested**

**Note:**

1. Enable push notification from capability section of xcode.
2. check twice your both p12 certificates uploaded on firebase project setting.
3. Device token only can get from real device not a simulator.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should import all required libs

```
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
```

later in AppDelegate.swift call next function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
        } else if let result = result {
            print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

confirm to MessagingDelegate protocol.

then you can add below delegate method and get the Firebase Token. (documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client )

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        // send to remote server
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
            } else if let result = result {
                print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but still if someone want to use in  Objective C.

Latest Firebase: 6.27.0

In iOS Objective C we can use like this

```
[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] instanceIDWithHandler:^(FIRInstanceIDResult * _Nullable result,
                                                            NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
            } else {
                token = result.token;
            }
            NSLog(@"Token %@", result.token);
           
        }];
```

and to get Instance Id:

```
 [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] getIDWithHandler:^(NSString *identity, NSError *error) {
         if (error != nil) {
           NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
         } else {
           NSLog(@"instance ID: %@", identity);
         }
         NSLog(@"IID %@", identity);
       }];
```

Answer (score -4):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {        
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("") { $0 + String(format: "%02X", $1) }

    print("APNs device token: \(deviceTokenString)"
}
```

Comment: What does this do? could you explain?