# Swift 3 Firebase Remote Notification not showing on TestFlight

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Good day, I have this app here that perfectly shows the notification on device plugged to Xcode but does not work when I try to run it on TestFlight or in the real application which has been already uploaded to the App Store. I have tried revoking and making new certificates but nothing. Help would be very much appreciated. Here is my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import CoreData


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]
        FIRApp.configure()

        // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                               name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)
        // [END add_token_refresh_observer]
        return true
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]
    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        // Won't connect since there is no token
        guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
            return
        }

        // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the InstanceID token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    }

    // [START connect_on_active]
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END connect_on_active]
    // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
    // [END disconnect_from_fcm]
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]
// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]
```

Comment: Is the concern only with receiving messages? Are you able to receive the registration token properly?

Comment: What do you mean receive the registration token? @AL. It shows the notification while it's attached as like a test device on Xcode but then does not show on TestFlight. Not sure if I have to mess with the device id token.

Comment: How are you sending messages? Through an App Server or Firebase Notifications Console? It would help to narrow down where the issue is if you could confirm that you are able to [generate a registration token in your app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37667753/4625829).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have uploaded the production APNs certificate in the firebase console. I think you have uploaded just the development APNs certificate hence you are able to get the notification with Xcode.Also for testing purpose use the firebase notification console to send notification, you just need to provide the device token in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in AppDelegate file

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
{
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)
}
```

you need to set APNS token for `sandbox` and `prod`.